# passing --single-transaction in mysqldump command line tool

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I'm using MySQL GUI tool to backup my innodb database and I use the option `'--single-transaction'` to get a consistent copy as backup.

I have however, noticed that if I backup using command line mysqldump tool, the backup process speeds up noticeably. I am wondering if is possible to mention **`--single-transaction`** in command line mysqldump utility?

Answer (score 3):

Sure enough, [`--single-transaction`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) is supported from the MySQL command line.

```
mysqldump --single-transaction databasename
```

Will use all of the default options from [`--opt`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_opt) (except for `--lock-tables`, which is overridden by `--single-transaction`) as well as [`--single-transaction`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction).

That really should be all there is to it.

I recommend briefly reading through all of the [options of mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) - you may find that some of them, like [`--routines`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines), are important for your database.

Comment: I know it's an old answer but I add this comment if other finds this. I have really tried to find out from the MySQL manuals if `--single-transaction` overrides `--lock-tables`. I couldn't find a clear statement otherwise than `The --single-transaction option and the --lock-tables option are mutually exclusive`. Perhaps it's obvious, but I rely on this answer. I hope it's still the case. MySQL 5.7.29.